# Filter somewhere is hijacking my orderby on WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, sql-order-by

There seems to be a plugin or script or SOMETHING that is hijacking my WP_Query, changing the "order_by" from "title" (what I set it to) to "post_date" and I can't find where it's happening. I've searched through all "add_filter" entries, all "post_date" entries and all "post_orderby" results within my plugins directory.

Is there I way I can "un-hijack" it or modify the WP_Query just before it runs?

Here is my code and the resulting query: http://pastebin.com/QRAaphMK

Comment: I figured out, I was using order_by and the parameter is orderby....

Answer (score 1):

Try filter `pre_get_posts` it runs just before Query sent to database to get posts.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'hijack_query' );
function hijack_query( $query ) {
// Do something with the query here
return $query;
}
```